# C++ - Vector iterator + offset out of range

Tags: c++, vector

I have looked at 10 or so answers about the same message but have yet to find my problem.

in level.h in the Level class:

```
std::vector<Bomb> m_bombs;
```

in level.cpp:

adding a bomb:

```
Bomb bomb;
bomb.owner = player;
bomb.power = power;
bomb.x = pos.x;
bomb.y = pos.y;
bomb.timer = 3.0f;
m_bombs.push_back(bomb);
```

checking bombs (every frame):

```
void Level::updateBombs(float dt)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_bombs.size(); i++)
    {
        m_bombs[i].timer -= dt;
        if(m_bombs[i].timer <= 0)
            m_bombs.erase(m_bombs.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

I am 100% sure the program crashes on the line where the erase function is called. I am able to output information from the vector which makes this way more confusing. The bombs are correctly in the vector. If I do m_bombs.remove_last() it removes the last element in the vector. Seem to just have problems with erase and begin().

Comment: Two comments: (1) if you `erase()` the element at index `i`, you will need to check index `i` again because the old index `i+1` was moved into `i`.  (2) It is not recommended to use a variable timestep in games, because it can cause unexpected behavior which is difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try erasing the vector backwards, e.g. if bomb index 3 and 5 to be erased, you remove the one with index 5 and then 3, because if you erase sequentially from `0` to `N-1`, by the time you erase index 3, then the index 5 will become index 4, which this can lead to out of bound when reaching the final step of the loop.

try this:

```
int pivot = 0
void Level::updateBombs(float dt)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_bombs.size(); i++)
    {
        m_bombs[i].timer -= dt;
        if(m_bombs[i].timer <= 0)
        {
            m_bombs.erase(m_bombs.begin() + i - pivot);
            pivot++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fix your code by using [erase-remove-idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

```
m_bombs.erase(std::remove_if(m_bombs.begin(), m_bombs.end(), 
                             [](const Bomb& b){ return b.timer < 0.0f;}), 
                             m_bombs.end());
```

Better split `updateBombs` function into two function:

```
updateBombs() does bomb timer update only
removeBombs() removes bombs which expired
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when clearing or creating vectors.
The problem occurred because 2 different versions of dlls where being used at runtime. The clearing and creating took place when calling Open CV functions which seem to use different runtime libraries than my visual studio.
Changing visual studio finally fixed the problem (I tried a lot of old OpenCV builds before changing visual studio but to no avail). VS 2008 and 2013 didn't work, VS2010 did.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `m_bombs.size()` with an `int` variable of your own that you decrement after removing a bomb. I've personally had problems with `.size()`. It's supposed to return the number of elements in the vector but I've had an empty vector and `.size()` returned numbers greater than zero.  Maybe trying this would help narrow down your problem.